# Can I make a report for a stored procedure with unknown amount of columns?

Tags: .net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a stored procedure, that generates some columns dynamically. I want to use Crystal Reports as a reporting service and, in particular, I need to generate report from this stored proc data. It's a poll-result report and for each poll act there is a row with it's ID and answers to the questions(one column for each question with questions IDs as headers). Customer has different forms with different number of questions, so **number of columns is unknown for a common report**.

---

So, the questions are:

1. Can I make the report view all columns from the returned dataset?
2. (If not,) Can I add fields to a existing report during runtime?
3. (If not,) Do you know any reporting services that can do such a thing? :)

P. S.: I know that the report design is really weird and this problem should not exist at all, but this is one of customer's demands...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I am aware of creaing n column reports is by using a Crystal Cros Tab Report (or Pivot Report)

Have a look at

- [Cross Tab Craziness in Crystal
  Reports](http://aspalliance.com/1689_Cross_Tab_Craziness_in_Crystal_Reports.all)
- [Creating a Crosstab Report in Visual
  Studio 2005 Using Crystal Reports](http://aspalliance.com/1041_Creating_a_Crosstab_Report_in_Visual_Studio_2005_Using_Crystal_Reports.all)

Comment: Big thanks for the articles and for the aspalliance itself! A've found many useful things on it and could make the demanded report, though without using that stored proc :)

Answer (score 0):

1 - No

2 - Crystal does have a report creation/modification api, but you need a license to their report server product to use it - it is not available to the built-in Crystal in Visual Studio, and I don't think you can use it in production if you have a desktop Crystal license - you would have to check with them for licensing details

3 - There are several of asp.net reporting components available which may allow you to do this (Telerik has one, and I know there are a couple of others) assuming your are using asp.net - otherwise, I don't know.

Could you just create separate-but-equal reports for the various survey flavors you have to deal with?